# Javascript array won't change inside of for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, reference

I am trying to rotate a 2dimensional array in javascript

the code outside the forloop to switch the values works but when i try to do that inside the for loop the variables are not changing

i think it is some sort of reference problem and i searched for that but i can't find a solution to this problem

```
temp = tempboard[0][1];
    console.log("unchanged:"+tempboard[0][1]+""+tempboard[6][1]);
    tempboard[0][1] = tempboard[6][1];
    tempboard[6][1] = temp;
    console.log("changed:"+tempboard[0][1]+""+tempboard[6][1]);
    
    for(i = 0; i < board.length; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < board[0].length; j++){
            /*a = tempboard[i][j];
            b = tempboard[j][i];
            temp = a;
            a = b;
            b = temp;
            console.log(a+" "+b);*/
            temp = tempboard[i][j];
            console.log("unchanged:"+tempboard[i][j]+""+tempboard[j][i]);
            tempboard[i][j] = tempboard[j][i];
            tempboard[j][i] = temp;
            console.log("changed:"+tempboard[j][i]+""+tempboard[i][j]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: you should declare variables correct way, use `let` or `const` (or `var` T_T) I think you should use let in your `for` and add let to temp declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it will be easier to build a new array based on the old one.

In the below code a new array is build in reverse based on the original one.

```js
arr = [[11, 12, 13], [21, 22, 23], [31, 32, 33], [41, 42, 43]];

console.log(JSON.stringify(Rotate2D(arr)));

function Rotate2D(array) {
  //Create a new empty array with the same size as the original one.
  let returnArr = [...Array(array.length)].map(e => Array(array[0].length));
  let maxIndexI = array.length - 1;
  let maxIndexJ = array[0].length - 1;

  //Fill the return array rotated
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < array[0].length; j++) {
      returnArr[maxIndexI - i][maxIndexJ - j] = array[i][j]
    }
  }
  return returnArr;
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks man
i cannot upvote you apearantly but you deserve thousands of upvotes :)

Comment: @MasterDragon No problem at all. You will get up voting privileges once you reach 15 reputation. What you can do is accept this answer as the answer to your question (if my answer is the answer you where looking for). You can do this with the checkmark on the left. This way people can see you don't need further assistance on you issue.

Comment: Really thanks for your answer
It was a reference error was it not?
as argument you pass the array in plain text(json) and then declare it as a variable again so it becomes its own array
am i right?

Comment: @MasterDragon The JSON has nothing to do with it. I just stringify the result as JSON to make the console output more readable. You can leave that out completly if you want to. I think the problem was that your logic mirrored the array twice ( index 1,2 -> 2,1 and later 2,1 -> 1,2. That's way you didn't see any results. Your logic also bugged if the 2D array was not a square (equal height/width).

Answer (score -1):

Try adding "let" keyword to your for loop, it could be an hoisting issue;

```
for(let i = 0; i < board.length; i++){
        for(let j = 0; j < board[0].length; j++){
            /*a = tempboard[i][j];
            b = tempboard[j][i];
            temp = a;
            a = b;
            b = temp;
            console.log(a+" "+b);*/
            temp = tempboard[i][j];
            console.log("unchanged:"+tempboard[i][j]+""+tempboard[j][i]);
            tempboard[i][j] = tempboard[j][i];
            tempboard[j][i] = temp;
            console.log("changed:"+tempboard[j][i]+""+tempboard[i][j]);
        }
    }
```